# How can I provide useful links which may answer a question.

Tags: support, specific-question, comment, answers, privileges

I am currently looking at providing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302141/chemistry-optimization-problems-using-calculus-i-methods) user with a resource which may answer their question, however I cannot add this as a comment as I do not have enough reputation. I am not sure if I should post it as an answer as I fear it may not be well received by the community(for not being a proper answer) and also the fact that it is just a resource link. Should I post this as an answer? Is there any way in which I can show them this resource?([resource](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematics_for_Chemistry))

Comment: WIth your permission, I can post it as a comment for you? Although, if the link answers the question, then you can simply answer the question. Do however make sure that it is not a "[link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)" answer

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I don't think it is necessary to post it as an answer, could you please post it as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Done! $\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!$

Comment: Thank you!!! :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: In general, link-only answers (even to questions asking for references) are bad.  Ideally, an answer on Math SE should be self-contained, and should make sense even if the link "rots".  In this case, where the poster is asking for references, a link is likely an appropriate *part* of a good answer, but such an answer should *also* contain a little bit of information about the linked resource (e.g. who is the intended audience?  what can actually be found on the other side of the link?  &c.).  Basically, give a short (≈100 words) abstract.

Comment: I would add to @Xander’s comment that one should try to mitigate the effects of eventual link rot if possible. Eg If it is a paper or book, a proper citation is helpful. If it is unpublished lecture notes, I have found the author, title and even file name(!) to be useful for after the author retires and loses their webpage